# can you help me with this? im trying to crete a simple calculator using python

Tags: python

ive been trying to run this code but the fuctions i have created are not being called

```
def add(*args,**kwargs):
    sum=0
    for m in args:
        sum=sum+m
    for n in kwargs.values():
        sum=sum+n
    return sum
def subtract(*args,**kwargs):

    sum=0
    for m in args:
        sum=m-sum
    for n in kwargs.values():
        sum=n-sum
    return sum

def multiply(*args,**kwargs):
    sum=1
    for m in args:
        sum=m*sum
    for n in kwargs.values():
        sum=n*sum
    return sum

def divide(*args,**kwargs):
    sum=1
    for m in args:
        sum=m/sum
    for n in kwargs.values():
        sum=n/sum
    return sum


def square(*args,**kwargs):
    sum=1
    for m in args:
        sum=sum*m**2
    for n in kwargs.values():
        sum=sum*n**2
    return sum

def Menu():
    print """
            What operation do you want to perform?
            1. Addition
        2. Subtraction
            3. Multiply
            4. Divide
            5. Square
            6. Exit
            """

    choice = input("Enter choice:")


    tup1= float(input("Enter numbers: "))


    if choice == ("1,add, Add"):
        print add()

    elif choice == ("2,subtract, Subtract"):
        print subtract()

    elif choice == ("3,multiply, Multiply"):
        print divide()

    elif choice == ("4,divide, Divide"):
        print multiply()

    elif choice == ("5,square, Square"):
        print multiply()

    elif choice == ("6,exit, Exit"):
        exit()
    else:

        Menu()
Menu()
```

Comment: If you are only just learning the basics, you should probably ignore Python 2, and spend your time on the currently recommended and supported version of the language, which is Python 3.

Comment: If you were to type in exactly the string `"1,add, Add"` you would see the `add` function return 0. There's a bit too much wrong here so I'm voting to close as too broad.

Answer (score 0):

`Choice` will never equal all of `("6,exit, Exit")`. What you want is

```
if choice in ("6","exit", "Exit"):
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below converts the `choice` string to lowercase, then checks if it matches anything in the list.

```
if choice.lower() in ['1','add']:
    print add(1,2,3)
```

Answer (score -1):

change the lines where you are checking for choices:

```
if choice == ("1,add, Add"):
```

to:

```
if choice in ["1", "add", "Add"]:
```

At the moment you are checking for an exact string